# How to pass container environment variable to docker compose exec commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have container **A** that has an environment variable called `VAR1` set.
If I do

```
docker-compose exec A env
```

I get the result

```
VAR1=VALUE1
```

Now, I need to pass this `VALUE1` to another command (lets call this as `command1`) in the same container, and I tried the following:

```
docker-compose exec A command1 $VAR1
```

Unfortunately, $VAR1 is evaluated in the local machine in which this command is run (remember this environment variable is set only inside container **A**).

How do I pass on specific container environment variables to commands that I run through `docker-compose exec`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute a shell in the container and pass it the entire command line quoted with single quotes to avoid evaluation on the host :

```
docker-compose exec A sh -c 'command1 $VAR1'
```